# Wordpress failing to sort and filter in same wp_query with meta values using relational operators

Tags: sorting, meta, wordpress, meta-key

I am trying to implement a filter and sort system for woo-commerce products in Wordpress.
There are two prices in my system (buy and rent)
Below is the argument array:

```
$args = array(
"post_type" => "product",
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
// This is to order by price
'meta_key' => '_regular_price',
'order'=>'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        // This is for getting price values greater than 1 in the ordering
        'key' => '_regular_price',
        'value' => 0,
        'compare'=>'>'
    ),
    array(
   "relation" => 'OR',
   array(
    "key" => array('_regular_price','rent_price'),
    "value" => array(1, 1000),
    "compare" => 'BETWEEN',
    "type" => 'DECIMAL'
    ),    
    array(

    "key" => array('_regular_price','rent_price'),
    "value" => array(5000, 10000),
    "compare" => 'BETWEEN',
    "type" => 'DECIMAL'
  ), 
)
```

),
);

If i remove the order by clause it works ok, or else if i remove the filter clause it works fine. But both of them together wont work.

Here are the conditions i am looking to implement:

- Order by buy price or rent price (No price range selected & Price > 0)
- Filter products between price range (single price range or multiple)
- Both of the above together